# About checkpoint_segments parameter

Tags: postgresql

I don't know the parameter "checkpoint_segments" very well, My personal views is that it means the
number of wal log files; I configured the value of the parameter to 64, but I can see 131 files in 
the pg_xlog directory.

Can someone explain the parameter?

```
--detail
postgres=# show checkpoint_segments;
 checkpoint_segments 
---------------------
 64
(1 row)

[postgres@pg_root]$ cd $PGDATA
[postgres@pg_root]$ ls -lrt pg_xlog | wc -l
132
```

Answer (score 6):

For background: WAL (write-ahead logging) is the mechanism for ensuring that the database can be recovered in the event of a crash without requiring the data files be flushed after every write. Basically, before any change is written to the data files, it is first logged. In the event of a crash, the log can be used to redo any changes that didn't make it to disk.

Each file in pg_xlog is a WAL segment. `checkpoint_segments`, along with `checkpoint_timeout`, controls when a WAL checkpoint is done (a checkpoint is done after `checkpoint_segments` segments have been filled or `checkpoint_timeout` seconds have passed, whichever comes first); a checkpoint is a moment in time where it is guaranteed that the data files have been flushed, so the redo process doesn't need to consider any transactions in the log from before the checkpoint.

According to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-configuration.html) (which is where I cribbed most of the above from), prior to 8.3 there will normally be `2 * checkpoint_segments + 1` segment files in the pg_xlog directory; since 8.3, the expected number is `(2 + checkpoint_completion_target) * checkpoint_segments + 1` (or `wal_keep_segments` in 9.0, if that is greater). In any case, 131 segment files for a `checkpoint_segments` of 64 is near the minimum to be expected.

Comment: According to your answer, I  understand the parameter now, Thanks you very much ! By the way,  can you explain checkpoint_completion_target?  I am new to postgresql, thanks !

Comment: Again according to the documentation, it controls how fast the checkpoint writes are performed. Setting it to 0.0 would be equivalent to the pre-8.3 behavior, writing as fast as possible and possibly temporarily overloading the computer's IO subsystem. Setting it to 1.0 would try to time it so that the checkpoint finishes just as it is time to do another checkpoint. Setting it somewhere in between causes it to write at a speed somewhere in between.

Comment: Suppose the value of checkpoint_timeout is 30 min, and the value of checkpoint_completion_target is 0.6, Is every checkpoint  process shoud finish it's job in 18 min(0.6 * 30) ?

Comment: I believe it looks at activity levels too. So even if `checkpoint_timeout` is 30 minutes, if activity levels indicate that checkpoints are required every 5 minutes it would aim at completing the checkpoint in 3 minutes. I don't know any details about how this estimation might work, though.

Comment: okey,thans for your explalation !